# Multiple Wifi networks - can't connect with VNC

Tags: networking, pi-2, raspbian-jessie

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B with a wireless USB adapter, Raspbian jessie. Until today I only had the raspy connected to my home network, everything was fine.

Now I have the necessity to bring the raspy with me, away from home. After reading several questions on how to set multiple wifi networks, I ended up with the following configuration:

This is my *wpa_supplicant.conf* file:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=IT

network={
    ssid="SSID1"
    psk="mypw"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    id_str="home"
}

network={
    ssid="SSID2"
    psk="mypw"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    id_str="android"
}
```

This is what I put into my *dhcpcd.conf* file:

```
# static IP address
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.51/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1

# # FOR WIFI
interface wlan0
arping 192.168.0.1
arping 192.168.43.1

# # FOR HOME
profile 192.168.0.1
static ip_address=192.168.0.52/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1

# # FOR ANDROID HOTSPOT
profile 192.168.43.1
static ip_address=192.168.43.52/24
static routers=192.168.43.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.43.1
```

When I'm home the raspy should connect to the home network (this works good). When I'm not home, I enable android hotspot and I power up the raspy. It should connect to the android hotspot. However, I'm not able to get a connection with VNC for Android to the static IP address I provided.

Here is what I tested so far:

- after powering up the raspy, I opened terminal emulator and used the command `ip neighbor`. This is the output: `192.168.43.82 dev wlan0 FAILED`. Why `192.168.43.82` and not `192.168.43.52`? I tried to connect to both these addresses but it failed.
- Then, without turning the hotspot off and keeping raspby on, I came home, plugged in the ethernet cable, connected with VNC, opened terminal and `ifconfig`: `wlan0` IP address was set to `192.168.43.52`. I tried to connect to this address with VNC from android, but it failed.
- With raspby GUI, I switched wifi to home network, then I switched again to android hotspot. This time I was able to connect with VNC from Android, using the ip address `192.168.43.52`.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to configure the static IP address for `wlan0`. By default, the Android Hotspot Tools has a DHCP server that answers the DHCP IP request of Raspberry Pi `wlan0` and then it gives an IP randomly.
If you are concerned about how to connect to raspberry pi without knowing the IP address, the answer is the `hostname`.

Install [NetX Network Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tools.netgel.netx&hl=en_US) on your android phone and try pinging `raspberrypi` or `raspberrypi.local` which is the default hostname. Obviously if you changed the hostname, ping that one.

After that you realized everything is fine, try VNC.

---

All you need is to comment all lines of `dhcpcd.conf` and change `wpa_supplicant` options as your environment.

Comment: Android never supported link-local addresses and mDNS so pinging `raspberrypi.local` will always fail.

Comment: @Ingo I didn't know about it BUT just tested with the application that I suggested (NetX Network Tools) and it's worked. I don't know why, can the application affected to this situation?

Comment: I'm astonished but interesting. Maybe mDNS is part of the *NetX Network Tools*?

Comment: @Ingo Not sure. I pinged a WS domain controller which AD configured. The domain is `mimtech` on `172.16.98.3` and `mimtech.local` the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Android but making a phone a hotspot does not magically turn it into a router.
Hotspots are to give you internet access.

Use a router or attempt to find a router app.

Setting a Static IP address for a hotspot seems strange. Hotspots should provide DHCP